# scipy curve_fit do not converge even if I iteratively change initial guess

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I have some points experimentally acquired.

These points should follow a theoretical function of these type :

f(x) = A * ( 1 -  e ^{-x/B})

I tried to use `curve_fit` function  from `scipy.optimize` to find the parameters A and B that best fits the exponential.

I have to perform this fit on almost 100 different samples.

Moreover I know by experience that 0.5 < A < 2.0 and 7.0 < B < 9.0 .

My problem is related to the failure in the convergence of curve_fit to the optimal values of A and B.

This is the code I wrote, first of all I import the packages that I need, I define the exponential function and then I define a fit function where I impose some constrains on the A value. I did this because othervise in some cases ( e.g. 10% of times) curve_fit returned me some irrealistic values for A , for example A  = 10^5  or even greater. If A is a value greater than 2 , I call again the curve_fit function, by changing the initial guess.

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

initial_guess = [8, 1]

def exponential(x, a, b):
    return a*(1 - np.exp(-(x)/b))

def fit(x, y, i):
    best_vals, covar = curve_fit(lambda t, a, b: exponential(t, a, b), x, y, p0=i)
    if best_vals[1]<0.5 or best_vals[1]>2:
            i2 = np.array([1, 0.8, 1])
            while best_vals[1]<0.5 or best_vals[1]>2:
                   i2 = i2 + [0.5, 0.1, 0.5]
                   best_vals, covar = curve_fit(lambda t, a, b: exponential(t, a, b), x, y, p0=i2)
                   print(best_vals)
                   variance = np.sqrt(np.diag(covar))
    i2= i        
    B = best_vals[0]
    A = best_vals[1]
    return variance, A, B

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
v, a, b = fit(df['x'], df['y'], initial_guess)
```

With this code unfortunately, sometimes I am not able to converge to a value of A between 0.5 and 2.0.

Does anyone suggest some other way to perform this fit by considering the constrain I have ?
Maybe there is a better way to write the fit function.. or to consider the constrains that I have and subsequently change the initial guess

Thanks who can help me

Andrea

Comment: the exponential in your code is different to the theoretical one in your post

Comment: you are right I made mistake in the text writing.. It is correct                                 f(x) = a*(1 - np.exp(-(x)/b))

Comment: Could you fix the code in the question?  It is much easier for someone to help you if the code runs without being edited.  It would also be helpful if you replaced the data from the file with some actual numbers that reproduce the problem.  You haven't provided `data.csv`, so no one can actually run this code as is.

Comment: I think there are a few problems with the code: 1) no point in reusing `lambda` in `curve_fit`, if your function is already defined. 2) What is `self.exponential` and why is it different? 3) The exponential in your code is different from the one in the question, which one is it? The one in the question can be fitted by a linear reg. taking log in both sides. 4) You can apply bounds to curve_fit using `bounds=[(a_min, b_min),(a_max, b_max)]]`, no need to `while` loop

Comment: Yes you are right, It was because I copy the code from a big class, and the exponential function was called with self.exponential. Now I corrected all in the question. I think that bounds can fix the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example graphical fitter using scipy's Differential Evolution genetic algorithm to determine initial parameter estimates for curve_fit(). The scipy implementation uses the Latin Hypercube algorithm to ensure a thorough search of parameter space, which requires bounds within which to search. In this example I have used your equation with an added offset so that it works with my test data. I also made he genetic algorithm search bounds on A and B slightly larger that the one you provided as a "margin of error" on the search bounds.

[image: plot]

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
import warnings

xData = numpy.array([19.1647, 18.0189, 16.9550, 15.7683, 14.7044, 13.6269, 12.6040, 11.4309, 10.2987, 9.23465, 8.18440, 7.89789, 7.62498, 7.36571, 7.01106, 6.71094, 6.46548, 6.27436, 6.16543, 6.05569, 5.91904, 5.78247, 5.53661, 4.85425, 4.29468, 3.74888, 3.16206, 2.58882, 1.93371, 1.52426, 1.14211, 0.719035, 0.377708, 0.0226971, -0.223181, -0.537231, -0.878491, -1.27484, -1.45266, -1.57583, -1.61717])
yData = numpy.array([0.644557, 0.641059, 0.637555, 0.634059, 0.634135, 0.631825, 0.631899, 0.627209, 0.622516, 0.617818, 0.616103, 0.613736, 0.610175, 0.606613, 0.605445, 0.603676, 0.604887, 0.600127, 0.604909, 0.588207, 0.581056, 0.576292, 0.566761, 0.555472, 0.545367, 0.538842, 0.529336, 0.518635, 0.506747, 0.499018, 0.491885, 0.484754, 0.475230, 0.464514, 0.454387, 0.444861, 0.437128, 0.415076, 0.401363, 0.390034, 0.378698])


# exponential equation + offset
def func(x, a, b, offset):
    return a*(1.0 - numpy.exp(-(x)/b)) + offset


# function for genetic algorithm to minimize (sum of squared error)
def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
    val = func(xData, *parameterTuple)
    return numpy.sum((yData - val) ** 2.0)


def generate_Initial_Parameters():
    minY = min(yData)
    maxY = max(yData)

    parameterBounds = []
    parameterBounds.append([0.0, 5.0]) # search bounds for a
    parameterBounds.append([5.0, 15.0]) # search bounds for b
    parameterBounds.append([minY, maxY]) # search bounds for offset

    # "seed" the numpy random number generator for repeatable results
    result = differential_evolution(sumOfSquaredError, parameterBounds, seed=3)
    return result.x

# by default, differential_evolution completes by calling curve_fit() using parameter bounds
geneticParameters = generate_Initial_Parameters()

# now call curve_fit without passing bounds from the genetic algorithm,
# just in case the best fit parameters are aoutside those bounds
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, geneticParameters)
print('Fitted parameters:', fittedParameters)
print()

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))

print()
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

Comment: Wow, very cool!! I didn't know about scipy's Differential Evolution genetic algorithm. Thanks a lot, it will be helpfull for me absolutly!!

Comment: Good *ranges* on parameter values are much easier to guesstimate than individual values. Like you, I am also of the opinion that this technique is filled with numerical genetic goodness.