# Curve Does not Fit (Python)

Tags: python, numpy

I made a curve fitting application but the curve does not fit truly. I can't solve that problem.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuJxo.png)

Here's my code btw.

```
import numpy as np
 

from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


c = [0.3, 0.5, 1,  1.2,  2.1, 2.5 ,2.88 ]

 

d = [20.93, 25.03, 35.75, 40.37, 66.32, 81.41, 104.52 ]
x = np.array(c)
y = np.array(d)


def test(x, a, b):
    return a * np.sin(b * x)
 
param, param_cov = curve_fit(test, x, y,)
 
print("Sine function coefficients:")
print(param)
print("Covariance of coefficients:")
print(param_cov)

 
ans = (param[0]*(np.sin(param[1]*x)))
 
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', color ='red', label ="data")
plt.plot(x, ans, '--', color ='blue', label ="fitted curve")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sine function is a bad choice for this fitting as you can see from the covariance values. The exponential function is a lot better. So you have chosen the wrong model.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

c = [0.3, 0.5, 1,  1.2,  2.1, 2.5 ,2.88 ]
d = [20.93, 25.03, 35.75, 40.37, 66.32, 81.41, 104.52 ]

x = np.array(c)
y = np.array(d)

def test(x, a, b):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x)
 
param, param_cov = curve_fit(test, x, y)
 
print("Exp function coefficients:")
print(param)
print("Covariance of coefficients:")
print(param_cov)

ans = test(x, *param)
 
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', color ='red', label ="data")
plt.plot(x, ans, '--', color ='blue', label ="fitted curve")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I am not sure about the method in which scipy fits the curve. Considering that you are using a sin function, multiple fits could be optimal. Please check this post, at the bottom it explains the use of evolutionary approach with SciPy that might fit your case more. [scipy curve_fit do not converge even if I iteratively change initial guess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56164659/scipy-curve-fit-do-not-converge-even-if-i-iteratively-change-initial-guess)

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to suggest a somewhat more automatic way to fit functions and data points (I don't know if it's useful/applies well to your case) but you should check and give a try to `numpy.polyfit` - the documentation and minimal examples can be seen [here.](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html)

Just to show how efficient the library is, let's check it running on your own data points with a third order polynomial fit using the simple following script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

c = np.array([0.3, 0.5, 1,  1.2,  2.1, 2.5 ,2.88 ])
d = np.array([20.93, 25.03, 35.75, 40.37, 66.32, 81.41, 104.52 ])

z = np.polyfit(c, d, 3)
p = np.poly1d(z)
xp = np.linspace(0, 3, 100)

plt.plot(c, d, 'o', label = 'data points')
plt.plot(xp, p(xp), '-', label = 'fit pol. 1-D')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

So, that code should return

[image]

without you having to concern about a function that will probably fit you points well, as @blunova brilliantly explained and demonstrated in the other answer (it will be ***really*** useful when you're dealing with a lot of data points.). You can even use higher order polynomials to fit your data, but notice that in some level they will fluctuate quite intensely and may end up becoming not so useful. You can use lowers too!

just at a example level, I'll leave a script with another order for you to compare:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import warnings 

c = np.array([0.3, 0.5, 1,  1.2,  2.1, 2.5 ,2.88 ])
d = np.array([20.93, 25.03, 35.75, 40.37, 66.32, 81.41, 104.52 ])

z = np.polyfit(c, d, 3)
p = np.poly1d(z)
xp = np.linspace(0, 3, 100)

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter('ignore', np.RankWarning)
    p30 = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(c, d, 30))

plt.plot(c, d, 'o', label = 'data points')
plt.plot(xp, p(xp), '-', label = 'fit pol. 3-order')
plt.plot(xp, p30(xp), '--', label = 'fit pol. 30-order')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

***OUTPUT:***
[image]